# Parse atom RSS feed with xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xml, rss

I had to parse a blogger RSS feed but I didn't have access to any third party modules like feedparser or lxml. I was stuck with the task of writing a library to parse RSS feeds; challenge accepted. I started by writing an RSS class and then an `Entry` class. I then realized that my classes only had two methods, one of them being `__init__`, so I scrapped the OOP approach and went for a more direct approach. I reduced everything down to one function `parse_feed`. `parse_feed` takes one positional argument: the URL to the RSS feed.

I'm curious what you think about the way I used `type` to create classes on the fly.

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3
#qpy:console

import urllib.request
from xml.dom import minidom


def parse_feed(url):
    # This is what parse_feed returns.
    feed = type('Feed', (object,), {})
    feed.entries = []

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as res:
        dom = minidom.parseString(res.read().decode('latin-1'))
        feed.title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        feed.link = dom.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].getAttribute('href')
        feed.published = dom.getElementsByTagName('published')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

    for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('entry'):
        title = element.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        link = element.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].getAttribute('href')
        author = element.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        published = element.getElementsByTagName('published')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        updated = element.getElementsByTagName('updated')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        _id = element.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        category = element.getElementsByTagName('category')

        tags = []
        for node in category:
            tags.append(node.getAttribute('term'))

        article = element.getElementsByTagName('content')[0].firstChild.nodeValue

        entry_dict = dict(
                    title=title, 
                    link=link, 
                    author=author, 
                    article=article,
                    tags=tags,
                    _id=_id)

        feed.entries.append(type('Entry', (feed,), entry_dict))

    return feed


# Example use.
feed_url = 'https://rickys-python-notes.blogspot.com/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=1000'
feed = parse_feed(feed_url)
print(feed.title)
print(feed.published)
for entry in feed.entries:
    print(entry.title)
    print(entry.link)
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope, nope, nope.

> ```
> feed = type('Feed', (object,), {})
> feed.entries.append(type('Entry', (feed,), entry_dict))
> ```

The entire point of OOP is to have pre-defined classes, as contracts to follow. Since your classes are always the same, you should just define them with the `class` keyword.  I recommend [attrs](http://attrs.org/) to make it look nicely.

In a good design, classes are *never* created on the fly, out of thin air.  They’re always defined in code, with a set of attributes that should also never change. (I’m not a fan of Python’s lenient style — Java, for example, makes it hard/impossible to create classes and new attributes at runtime.)

Or alternatively, you could make those regular lists of regular dicts.  Not everything needs to be a class.

More complaints:

- `Entry` should not inherit from `Feed`. They’re two separate, unrelated things.
- > ```
  > dom = minidom.parseString(res.read().decode('latin-1'))
  > ```

  99% of feeds in the wild are in UTF-8, and you should check the encoding in the `<?xml ?>` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the previous answer, creating classes on the fly is against the OOP philosophy.

Another problem is with `parse_feed()`: it does several things at time. This is against the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle. A function is supposed to achieve one goal, and only that one. This facilitates code reuse and unit testing.

I would suggest creating a class   which  has  3 functions to implement the 3 main tasks I see `parse_feed()` is doing.